# stop future dates constraint oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a customer table and i wan't to add the following constrain

```
ALTER TABLE Customer ADD CONSTRAINT dateOfBirth CHECK(dateOfBirth <= sysdate);
```

i am getting the following error message

> SQL Error: ORA-02436: date or system variable wrongly specified in CHECK constraint

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Oracle doesn't allow volatile functions in `check` constraints.  I think you have to use a trigger.

Comment: As @GordonLinoff mentioned, this activity is not allowed. Here's the documentation that outlines the rule: https://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.3.0/ref/rrefsqlj13590.html; Specifically:  "The search condition must always return the same value if applied to the same values. Thus, it cannot contain any of the following:
Dynamic parameters (?);
Date/Time Functions (CURRENT_DATE, CURRENT_TIME, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
Subqueries;
User Functions (such as USER, SESSION_USER, CURRENT_USER)"

Answer (score 3):

As @GordonLinoff says, you can't use a constraint with a non-deterministic function.  You can create a trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_no_future_births
  BEFORE INSERT ON customer
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF( :new.dateOfBirth > sysdate )
  THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR( -20001, 'Date of birth cannot be in the future.' );
  END IF;
END;
```